# Pulling values from forms text fields to other locations in ruby on rails html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, textfield, form-for

I am new to ruby on rails and am composing a library for books. Most of it is working except for moving a scanned in isbn from a text field on a page to another text field.

```
<%= form_for @book, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :isbn, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :isbn, :class => 'text_field' %>
      <%= link_to t('.new_autofill', :default => t("helpers.links.Auto Fill")),
            autofill_books_path( :isbnvalue => :isbn ),
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
```

The code above takes the value isbn and passes it into the controller that sets up the page autofill. I need the isbn text_field value, not its label value which is what I think I am obtaining. How do i grab this value? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to do that as outlined in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808519/getting-value-of-html-text-input).

If you want to do it with rails, you can create a new action in the book controller and link to it in the form instead of `autofill_books_path`, for instance `get_isbn`:

```
def get_isbn
  @isbn = params[:book][:isbn]

  redirect_to autofill_books_path(isbnvalue: @isbn)
end
```

Of course you should include validation to check if the isbn provided is correct.