# Work around to change HTML file input value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, file-io

I am trying to automate a file upload process for a courier we use. I need to upload a CSV file with a form on there website. But it seems I cannot use the DOM to change the input value for a file input.

Is there a way I can do this? I am trying to do it like this;

...Document.getelementbyid("userFile").innertext = filepath

But it doesn't change?

Any idea

Comment: Because inputs don't have `innerText` or `innerHTML`, but `value`. Also, khm, proper capitalisation.

Comment: a little known-fact: you can leave the file input populated, then every time you call `new FileReader().read()`, it will grab the current file contents, updates and all. so, if you left your page open, you can run a poll on the input and upload changes when they happen. i made the watchfile lib for this purpose: https://github.com/rndme/watchfile

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .value for HTML inputs.

As seen here:
[Getting value of HTML text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808519/getting-value-of-html-text-input)

> document.getElementById('email').value;

or

```
Document.getelementbyid("userFile").value = filepath
```

Comment: value will not update file input as supposedly its a security thing in browsers. Any ideas how to get round it?

Comment: im trying to put a string value to the file into the .value is this right?

Comment: @user3348264 Yes it is. Show us your code or check for mistakes by yourself :)

Comment: Document.getelementbyid("userFile").Value = filepath

Comment: Maybe: 'document.getelementbyid("userFile").value = "filepath";' Does that work (even if it's not what you want to achieve, i guess, because you certainly use filepath as a variable)? I recommend FireBug for FireFox to debug your web code.

Comment: can cannot set a file input to a path with a string, and magically have it populate with a file as though the user really picked it out. it just will not work.